# 「オンラインジャッジ」 のタグは不適切(不要)か

Tags: 討議, タグ

aoj ( aizu online judge ) にまつわる質問がいくつか投稿されていたので、「オンラインジャッジ」 のタグを作成して、追加していっていました。

先ほど確認したところ、不要タグとして削除されていましたが、これはタグとして有用ではない、、のでしょうか。

だとしたら、タグを作る、付与するにあたっての基準はありますか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

タグの主な目的は「検索や分類に使うキーワード」もしくは「タイトルの代わりに前提条件や質問の種類を伝え、他のユーザーが一覧上で取捨選択するための目印」だと考えています。

オンラインジャッジに提出するコードに関する質問は、技術的には標準入出力を使ったプログラムというだけで、それ以外の質問と区別する必要性があまり感じられません。オンラインジャッジに関する質問だから回答できる・できない、役に立つ・立たないということもないでしょう。

この場合は質問の経緯・背景として本文にでも書けば十分かなと、私は考えます。

強いて言えば「[Aizu Onlineジャッジの問題について(presentation error)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/24300/8000)」はオンラインジャッジであることに依存した質問、というかAOJの使い方についての質問ともとれますが・・・オンラインジャッジタグを新設するほどかと言われると微妙なところですね。

Comment: オンラインジャッジで問われる問題には、比較的オンラインジャッジ特有の特徴があるような気がしているので、タグを作ったのですが、まぁ検索・分類の目的ではそこまで役にたたなさそうである、ということならば、必要ないのかもしれません。